# Values for submodel properties is always null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using view to generate hidden field but the value is always null. Here is my code. Not sure what is wrong. I have list of FillRequest which contains Id and Name properties. it is part of submodel.

```
@using Computs.Models
@model RequestViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, id = "PostForm", class = "form-horizontal" ))
{
 foreach(var reqest in Model.FillRequest)
 {
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>reqest.Id)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>reqest.Name)
 }
 <button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
}
```

After inspecting the post method in controller the Id and Name properties are always null.

Here is the model.

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public String TypeOfRequest { get; set; }
    public List<FillRequest> FillRequests { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller get method

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var requestModel = new RequestViewModel();
        requestModel.FillRequests = new List<FillRequest>();
        requestModel.FillRequests.add(new FillRequest() { Id = 1, Name = "John"});
        requestModel.FillRequests.add(new FillRequest() { Id = 2, Name = "Terry"}); 

        return View(requestModel);
         
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing how do you prepare the model returned to the view and how do you declare that model inside the view is difficult to say anything about the problem. Just guesses

Comment: I answered your question, but in hindsight, you should be getting errors, not nulls.  Your model's list property is `FillRequests`, plural, but you instantiate it and then populate the singular `FillRequest`.  Even if that weren't the issue, I believe your loop logic should also create an error, not return a null.  Did you try to create a simplified example but not check that the simplified code works?  Even if so, I hope my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For-each loops don't allow you to tie the lambda in @Html.HiddenFor() to a model element.  Notice tha tyou pass the parameter 'm' but don't use it:

```
foreach(var reqest in Model.FillRequest)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>reqest.Id)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>reqest.Name)
}
```

Instead use a For loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Model.FillRequest.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.FillRequest[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.FillRequest[i].Name)
}
```